# google OAuth 2.0 particular domain

Tags: django, google-oauth

With Google OAuth 2.0, is that possible to filter the users by their domain?

I basically understand the google Oauth 2.0. It can provide authentication and authorization which is great. However, with authentication, I only want my site accept user with a particular domain (not @gmail, but @example.com). Is that possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably adding 'hd=example.com' to the OAuth2 requests will have the desired result (pretty much like in a [Google OAuth1 flow](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref#GetAuth)).

Note however that the user could modify the request and remove or change the 'hd' value. So adding a particular value to the hd parameter does not guarantee that a specific Google Apps domain was used. You should still do additional checks once you get a response.

Hope that helps.